# Integral with Simpson's method not converging

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

I'm trying to use Simpson's rule to integrate the following function in a program:

$$\int_{z_a}^{z_b}\frac{Cf(z)}{(C^2 - f(z)^2)^{3/2}}\,dz$$

where $C$ is a constant and $f(z)$ are interpolated values from a table based on $z$ and it can vary from $1400$ to $1600$ with $C > f(z)$.

I'm probably missing something obvious here. My understanding is that when using Simpson's rule the output should converge to at least the "vicinity" of the "true" answer depending on the number of segments.

But every time I increase the segments, the output value always increases and never converges. This graph shows the output ($y$ axis) using segments from $100$ to about $920,000$ ($x$ axis):

[image: Graph]

I've tested this program with other integrals and with less than $1000$ segments I always get the expected result, so I believe the algorithm is correct. It is from the book "*Numerical Methods for Engineers*"

Is this function not suitable to be evaluated using Simpson's method? Is there another method to numerically evaluated this specific integral?

Comment: So you have $C>f(z)$; do you have any regions where $C$ is actually quite close to $f(z)$? Those regions will make the integrand big, which will make Simpson's rule slow to converge. You can counteract that using an adaptive quadrature method (also other possibilities).

Comment: Another remark: an upper bound on your integral would be $(z_b-z_a) \frac{1600C}{(C^2-1600^2)^{3/2}}$. Are you going beyond this bound with your Simpson calculation by any significant amount? If so, then your method has an error.

Comment: @Ian Indeed $f(z)$ gets very close to $C$ many times! That is the problem and I hadn't realized that. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll see if I can modify where I get $C$ from.